# image compiled with -fPIC and -pie not loading

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, aslr

compiled code with the -fPIC and -pie option and with certain checks able to see that binary generated is not havinf TEXTREL and position independent.

But once i load the image i can see that it is terminating, tried to get the exit status with below step in a script, getting the pid and exit status 0

```
./testASLR-image -n 2048 -m 100 -M 400 -c /config | tee -a /dev/console &
new_pid = $!                                                                   
+echo "pid new in while is $new_pid and ! value $!" | tee -a /dev/console $BOOTLOG_FILE
+wait $!                                                                        
+echo "exit status is $?" | tee -a /dev/console $BOOTLOG_FILE
```

it seems returning 0. also it is not entering the main(), no print from main is coming on console.

added signal handler and core generation, it is not generating coredump.

my module use many kernel module and library, Is there any dependency on the shared libray which can cause such loading failure? is there any way to find if my binary is having any such library usage?

Comment: The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the *last* program in it, so the 0 is the exit status of `tee -a /dev/console`, which unsurprisingly succeeded.

Comment: ok.. got it.. will get the exit status, is there any dependency for which load is failing?

Comment: Hard to say without more details.  You may want to run `ldd` on your binary to see about its dependencies.  Running it in the foreground, without piping the output, may also make it easier to diagnose.  Note that your pipe won't capture the standard error, which is where any relevant error messages would probably go.